# How many mappers and reducers would be advised to process 2TB of data in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to develop a Hadoop project for one of our clients. We will be receiving a data of around 2 TB per day, so as a part of reconciliation we would like to read the 2 TB of data and perform sorting and filter operations.

We have set up the Hadoop cluster with 5 data nodes running on t2x.large AWS instances containing 4 CPU cores and 16GB RAM. What is the advisable count of mappers and reducers we need to launch to complete the data processing quickly?

Comment: Isn't this a how-long-is-a-piece-of-string question? I presume it would depend on how long your operations take, and how many it would need to do - as far as I know that can't be determined from the knowledge that you have 2TB of data.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this:

http://crazyadmins.com/tune-hadoop-cluster-to-get-maximum-performance-part-1/

http://crazyadmins.com/tune-hadoop-cluster-to-get-maximum-performance-part-2/

This depends on the task nature if it is RAM or CPU consuming and how parallel your system can be.

If every node contains 4 CPU cores and 16GB RAM. On average I suggest 4 to 6 map-reduce task on each node.

Creating too much mapred tasks will degrade your cpu performance and you may face container problems regarding not enough memory.

Comment: @Mosan: +1 for links you shared